# Cordova facebook plugin - share without login

Tags: android, facebook, cordova, plugins, share

I am using the official Cordova Facebook Plugin in my app. The .login() and .showDialog() works fine. But I would like to be able to use the showDialog() for facebook sharing WIHTOUT forcing the user to login through facebook.

According to the Facebook documentation, this should be possible.

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/sharing/reference/share-dialog

But in my app I get an error:

facebookConnectPlugin.showDialog({method:"feed", link:"http://bah.com"}, dialog_succes, function(obj){alert('share error: '+JSON.stringify(obj));});

share error: No active session

Comment: "The Share dialog prompts a person to publish an individual story or an Open Graph story to their timeline." How would Facebook know to which timeline publish a share, if user is not logged in with FB account? There is no chance to do that.

Comment: Read the next line: "This does not require Facebook Login or any any extended permissions"

It is possible because the Facebook app already knows who you are. My app simply opens the facebook app for you.

Comment: Sure, but it means that the sharing button can be shown without having user logged in. For the sharing action itself you will have to get user authenticated. It's a bit like saying that you want to send emails without opening your email account. But you are right, Facebook docs might be tricky.

Comment: Ok. But shouldn't I be able to send the user to the facebook app (in order to share a link) without first opening the facebook app and having the user approve my single-signon?

Comment: I mean like a website the shows a "Share" button. The website simply sends the user to facebook. It does require them to approve a facebook app or signle-signon.

Comment: Hey I have the same problem and the exact same question.. Have you figured it out yet?

Comment: I have the same issue too, did anyone come up with a solution.

Comment: Same issue here as well